# Why my scanf catch the order that I give from my Popen

Tags: python, c, scanf

**TL;DR: How to make my scanf(must be scanf) reads the input from a python?**

So I have this file in python

```
import subprocess
import sys

process=subprocess.Popen(["canCHandleIt.exe"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=process.communicate(2)
print res[0]
```

The point is simple. I want my C to catch the number "2" and print success twice, as my c code suggested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x;int o;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for (o=0;o<x;o++){
    printf("Sucsess!");
    }
}
```

But it just stops. Of course if type the number 2, then it will work, but I want my scanf works alone.

Some may suggest that I should just used C equivalent to Python's `sys.stdin.readline()`, but I really want my scanf works without human interference. (The reason I asked this, is because I often people use scanf in contest and I want to replicate the contest bot,in python obviously.)

You can assume that I have gcced my c file.

Comment: Pardon me? I'm making this file so I can do this automatically, without human interference (and it also depends on input, so, I cant hard coded it). This is part of my learning process, so please understand why I bother.

Comment: you cannot send 2 with `communicate`, it has to be a string. Try `"2\n"` with new line character added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

process=subprocess.Popen(["canCHandleIt.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=process.communicate('2')
print res[0]
```

...the key differences being `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` passed to `Popen()`, and passing "2" as a string, not an `int`, into `communicate()`.

It is documented for [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) that :

> The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process.....

and

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE.